# Java App as a Linux Service issue with permissions

Tags: java, linux, permissions

I want to start my Java app as a Linux service. I created a wrapper file:

> ```
> SERVICE_NAME=ConfigurationService PATH_TO_JAR=/opt/Applications/Configuration-Service/configuration-service.jar PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/ConfigurationService-pid case $1 in
> start)
>     echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
>     if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
>         nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
>                     echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
>     else
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
>     fi
> ;;
> stop)
>     if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
>         PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
>         kill $PID;
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
>         rm $PID_PATH_NAME
>     else
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
>     fi
> ;;
> restart)
>     if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
>         PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
>         kill $PID;
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
>         rm $PID_PATH_NAME
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
>         nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
>                     echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
>     else
>         echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
>     fi
> ;; esac
> ```

However, when I start it with command:

> service ConfigurationService start

The app start but does not have permissions to connect to DataBase. When I invoke my web API I can see such error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If I start my application using command it works without issues:

```
java -jar ConfigurationService.jar &
```

I understand that it is something related to users and permissions but I am new in Linux configuration. Appreciate any help